# Replace: Could not convert string to float ' ' or '[text]'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, replace, type-conversion

I have a large CSV with some columns containing data as shown
[image: here]
I want to get rid of unnecessary text and convert the remaining digits from string to float to just leave the values.

I am using

```
    Added['Household Occupants'] = Added['Household Occupants'].str.replace(r'[^0-9]', '').astype(float)
```

and

```
    Added['Grocery Spend'] = Added['Grocery Spend'].str.replace(r'\D', '').astype(float)
```

and these do the job perfect, but when I apply the same to 'Electronics Spend' and 'Goods Spend' columns, i get errors like;

'ValueError: could not convert string to float: '''
and
'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Goods''

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a *good example* where [`pandas.Series.name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) can be useful :

```
out = (
        Added.apply(lambda x: x.replace(f"{x.name.capitalize()}\((\d+)\)", r"\1",
                                        regex=True)
                               .astype(float))
      )
```

Another alternative with [`pandas.Series.str.extarct`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
out = Added.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract("\((\d+)\)", expand=False).astype(float))
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

      Household Occupants  Grocery Spend  Electronics Spend  Goods Spend
0                     1.0          500.0             5000.0         50.0
1                     4.0           45.0              200.0          0.0
2                     NaN            NaN                NaN          NaN
3                     5.0            NaN                NaN          NaN
4                     3.0            NaN                NaN          NaN
1337                  4.0            NaN                NaN          NaN
1338                  4.0            NaN                NaN          NaN
1339                  4.0          200.0                NaN          NaN
1340                  4.0            NaN                NaN          NaN
1341                  NaN            NaN                NaN          NaN
```